# Use texture array for spritesheets?

Tags: opengl, spritesheet

To save texture bind there is the technique to use a sprite sheet which combines several sprites into one texture. Now if I have more sprites than which will fit into one sprite sheet (limited by GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE), can I just use a texture array with multiple sprite sheets and still use only one texture bind?
Is the limiting factor for the amount of sprites the gpu memory?

Comment: GPU memory and GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS ("OpenGL 4.5 requires that the limit be at least 2048, while OpenGL 3.3 requires it be at least 256.")

Comment: @JBeuer It seems that you know the answer to the question. Why don't you post a more extended answer?